# Gridview Hyperlink to XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 which contains Results (Pass/Fail) as well as XML (Complete set of Results), the columns containing XML are VARCHAR(MAX).

I also have a Grid View bound to that data source.

What I would like is to use a hyperlink field in the columns containing the XML, which will open a new page displaying the XML (rather than displaying all the xml in the column).

Is this possible? Any Alternatives if not?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `template column` in grid view which will have the hyperlink

in this column you can specify the `command name` and `command argument` the id of column

In code behind in grid item command  check for this command name

redirect to another page with id and show xml there